# Extending a class from an npm package in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, npm

I am creating 2 npm packages, and I am writing them in typescript:

Let's call them "core" and "module"
In "core" I export a class in my index.ts file. It's just a simple class

```
class Agent {}
```

In "module" I import that class, and I extend it. I get this error:

```
import { Agent } from 'core';
class Extension extends Agent {}
```

`"Type { ... } is not a constructor function type"`

When I click on it, it takes me to the compiled version of it and it's a nasty looking function.

Any way of solving this issue ?

Comment: Can you post that 'nasty looking function'? Do you have declaration files in your core package (`*.d.ts` files). If you haven't got definition files TypeScript won't know what `Agent` is

Comment: The nasty looking function: https://pastebin.com/7BTWXzyr I don't know if this is a good thing but I have a defs.ts file, and I export all those files as "Types" (I was trying things out, but it doesn't seem like it's working)

Comment: And no I don't have *.d.ts files looking at it right now.

Comment: The transpiled function looks right. I think the problem is that you don't have a definition file that tells TypeScript so. Can you post that `defs.ts` file?

Comment: Thank you for the help, it was because I removed `declaration: true`

Answer (score 0):

It was because I was a noob and I added in compilerOptions `allowJs: true`, so I had to remove `declaration: true`. Now it's back like that.

Thanks to Oscar Paz that asked about those *.d.ts files in the comment above.

Comment: I was thinking about `declaration: true` precisely, that's why I asked you that. Glad you solved your issue